# Is it possible to be infected without installing anything like said at the beginning of the video?

Tags: malware, mobile, keyloggers

It seems like a 'crazy' claim that John McAfee makes at the very beginning of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klj99FL-QV8), is it true?

> "Over half of all smartphones, both iOS and Android are infected with
> keystroke logging software. This is a known fact.
>
> People pay these pornography sites for the ability to put their key
> logging software on your phones. How do you think they make their
> money? It costs millions of dollars to maintain these massive
> databases and have the bandwidth to disperse this pornography, and yet
> you don't pay. Yes, you're paying."

If this is true, how is it possible? I thought usually to be infected you had to execute/ install something, and that most websites were safe since they're sandboxed in the browser be it on a Mac or iOS/Android.

If true, how would you go about finding traces to see if your Mac or Android for example were compromised? Is it even possible to do for a user? All I know is Malwarebytes on a Mac/Pc, but maybe that's not enough?

Comment: Note that he justifies his claim merely by saying "This is a known fact", yet there is no reference to any publication supplying any data to it. He also doesn't go into detail how this would be possible technically, or by showing a PoC. And as we all know: **PoC or GTFO**

Comment: Infection is always possible if there's a zero day exploit.  One would hope the window before that gets patched is small...  But claiming that half of phones are infected unlikely.  Although half of ones that visit porn sites I might actually believe.

Comment: This exact video was already discussed here: [How seriously should we take this commentary from John McAfee? If it's serious, what do we do?](/q/255820/129883)

Comment: @schroeder : Sorry, I edited my post and added transcription.
FireQuacker : Thanks for the link ! But the discussion doesn't answer all my questions though !

Comment: It is, unfortunately, a duplicate. And we've tackled the claims. Is it true? There is no evidence for it. Since the rest of your questions depend on it being true, then there is no way to answer them.